# Can't find the android.support.v4.provider package in my support library

Tags: android

According to the android SDK manager i have the latest version of android-support-v4.jar (19.1)
I extracted the content of it, but still I cant find any directory with name "provider" in it.
According to the google documentation such package exists. 
Anyone had the same issue before?

PS: I still use eclipse ADT

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

> According to the android SDK manager i have the latest version of android-support-v4.jar (19.1)

The latest version of the Android Support Library is 22.2.1, not 19.1. I think that the class that you are seeking (the backport of `DocumentFile`) is in a newer edition of the JAR than 19.1.

Comment: can you give me a download link for the latest version? my sdk manager wont show that update :(

Comment: @ManZzup: "can you give me a download link for the latest version? " -- not readily. "my sdk manager wont show that update :(" -- then you are probably not getting lots of other updates, and you really need to fix that problem. In your SDK Manager, click on Tools > Options, then click the "Clear Cache" button. Close the options dialog, and choose Pacakges > Reload.

Comment: oh i found the weirdest thing, tried the ^above method but still it says 19.1 is the latest. Then i opened android studio and check the sdk manager that comes with it. Guess what i shows 22.2 as an update :/